# Html <video> first-frame poster on iPad

Tags: html5-video

I'm trying to have a video that loads the first frame of the video as the poster but doesn't autoplay. I need it to work on desktop, iPad, and iPhone.

**Desktop:** You don't need anything special, this will load the first frame as a poster

```
<video> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

**iPhone:** This takes a bit of a hack since on iPhone the poster isn't automatically loaded. By adding "autoplay" the browser loads the first frame as the poster, but without adding "muted playsinline" it won't actually autoplay

```
<video autoplay> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

**iPad:** The iPad acts like the iPhone by not pulling the poster by default, but if you add in "autoplay" like I do on iPhone it actually autoplays which I don't want.

So how would I go about pulling in the first frame of the video as the poster without it trying to autoplay the video on load?

I've also tried preload="metadata" and it did not work.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like adding the time for 0.1 seconds does the trick too.

```html
<video>
  <source src="1616911307745.mp4#t=0.1" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: this is genius and no need for autoplay

Comment: omg you're a genius bro, u saved my life!!

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem by adding autoplay to my video tag and pausing the video on load this way:

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
 myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" autoplay controls> 
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to [Hemmingsen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53828195/2568259) but instead of using the `onload` event on the window object you can use `onLoadedData` on the video element itself instead:

```js
function handleLoadedData(event) {
  event.target.pause();
}
```

```html
<video autoplay onLoadedData="handleLoadedData(event)"> 
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

PS: The key here is to use `autoplay` on the video so **Safari** will load the poster image but immediately stop the video after load so it won't autoplay it.